# Scala implicit read and write for multi layered map

Tags: json, scala, dictionary

I have defined a multi-layered map:

```
import collection.mutable.Map
var modelsRef = Map[String,Map[String,Array[String]]]()
```

and filled it with data; for example by using:

```
myMap.update("a", Map("b1" -> Array("c","d","e","f")))
myMap("a").update("b2", Array("g","h"))
```

I'd like to write the result in a `json` file and later read it from the file and re-built the map structure. I am using the maven Scala and I am thinking to use the `Play` or an equivalent package. I read in other posts that I need to define a `case class` and then write an `implicit Writer and Reader`. I appreciate it if anyone can show me what it may look like for such a complicated multi-layered map?

Comment: Using `Array` in model API is not recommended (mutable).What have you already tried with the json lib you've chosen?

Comment: I tried the solution Ivan suggested. But I received the following two errors: "could not find implicit value for parameter encoder" and "not enough arguments for method asJson". I appreciate it if you have any suggestion on how to resolve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define any special case class as most of json libraries support "base" types like Map, String, Array, etc by default.

Example done with [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/).

```
  import scala.collection.mutable
  import io.circe.parser._
  import io.circe.syntax._

  var map = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]]]()
  map.update("a", mutable.Map("b1" -> mutable.ArrayBuffer("c", "d", "e", "f")))
  map("a").update("b2", mutable.ArrayBuffer("g", "h"))
  val json = map.asJson.pretty(Printer.noSpaces)

  println(json)
  // {"a":{"b2":["g","h"],"b1":["c","d","e","f"]}}
  println(decode[Map[String, Map[String, Seq[String]]]](json))
  // Right(Map(a -> Map(b2 -> List(g, h), b1 -> List(c, d, e, f))))
```

Notice that you aren't required to use mutable collections to read the json back into structure. In my example, I used immutable collections in `decode` method.

**Update**:

I tested the above code with Scala 2.12.8 and circe 0.11.2. 
Dependencies for maven are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.circe</groupId>
    <artifactId>circe-parser_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Any suggestion on why I receive the following errors for val json = map.asJson.pretty(Printer.noSpaces): 1) Error: could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]]]] 2) Error: not enough arguments for method asJson: (implicit encoder: io.circe.Encoder[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]]]]) io.circe.Json.
Unspecified value parameter encoder.

Comment: To provide more info, I added 'circe-parser_2.11' to my maven pom to activate those 'import io.circe' lines. I also tried to add 'import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}' in my code, but, it remained grayed out and didn't help removing the above errors.